# How to change color of specific elements in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a sorting Visualizer using React. Right now, I am implementing BubbleSort. The program looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
class Sorter extends Component {

    state = {
        array: [100,4,214,55,11,22,10,33],
        color: "blueviolet",
    } 

    bubblesorter = async () => {
        let arr = this.state.array
        var len = arr.length,
        i, j, stop;
            for (i=0; i < len; i++){
                    for (j=0, stop=len-i; j < stop; j++){
                        if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]){
                            swap(arr, j, j+1);
                        } 
                        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
                        this.setState({array:arr})
                    }
                }   
    }

    render() {
        const array = this.state.array
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is a sorter</h1>
                <div className="container">
                    {array.map((value, id) => (
                        <span>
                            <div className="bar" key={id} style={{height: value+"px", backgroundColor: this.state.color}}  >
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.bubblesorter}>Sort</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The sorting functionality works correctly. But I would like to change the color of bars (array elements being compared). Can someone help with the Logic which can be used to implement this...Thanks

Comment: Do you just need a different color to be applied to all of the bars in each loop?

Comment: I tried updating the state with another color inside the loop, but that changes the color of all the bars...I just want color change of bars being compared...I don't exactly know how to go about this :(

Comment: @yash No...I want a single color change of the bars being compared (and only during comparison)

Comment: Trying to build a simpler version of something like this https://alexzajac.github.io/ReduSort/

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `colors` array and update the color which was only changed.

```js
class Sorter extends Component {
    state = {
        array: [100, 4, 214, 55, 11, 22, 10, 33],
        colors: Array(8).fill('blueviolet'),  // Array of colors for each bar
    };

    bubblesorter = async () => {
        ...
                await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
                
                // Set different item's color as `red`
                const colors = arr.map((item, index) => (this.state.array[index] === item ? 'blueviolet' : 'red'));
                this.setState({ array: arr, colors });
            }
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { array, colors } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is a sorter</h1>
                <div className='container'>
                    {array.map((value, id) => (
                        <span>
                            <div
                                className='bar'
                                key={id}
                                // <- Use the color at the same index of the item
                                style={{ height: value + 'px', backgroundColor: colors[id] }}
                            ></div>
                        </span>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.bubblesorter}>Sort</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work...but thanks to your logic, i was able to write a code that works...although it can be improved...Have posted it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Tried this...it works but can be improved using modern javascript (not that familiar with it, suggestions welcome)

```
class Sorter extends Component {

    state = {
        array: [],
        colors: Array(8).fill('blueviolet'),
    } 
    bubblesorter = async () => {
    ...
                        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
                        const colors = []
                        for (let k=0; k<8; k++) {
                            let color = k==j || k==j+1 ? 'red':'blueviolet'
                            colors[k] = color
                        }
                        // console.log(colors)
                        this.setState({ array: arr, colors: colors });
             
              }
      }
      render() 
      {
        // const array = this.state.array
        const { array, colors } = this.state;
        // console.log(array)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is a sorter</h1>
                <div className="container">
                    {array.map((value, id) => (
                        <span>
                            <div 
                                className="bar" 
                                key={id} 
                                style={{ height: value + 'px', backgroundColor: colors[id] 
                             }} >
                            </div>
                            {/* <span>{value}</span> */}
                        </span>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.bubblesorter}>Sort</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```